# I cant seem to run a AHK script ONLY when I insert the sd card

Tags: autohotkey

I have been looking into this for a few days ♫ And i still haven't found what I'm looking for♫ The problem is that the script runs when I insert the sd card AND when I take it out. Any suggestions to how I could get it to just run on insert?

Code:

```
#Persistent
OnMessage(0x219, "notify_change")


notify_change(wParam, lParam, msg, hwnd)
{

send, <#{right}
sleep, 100
MouseClick, left, 726, 615
send, ^a
sleep, 100
send, ^c
sleep, 100

GroupAdd, ExplorerGroup,,ShellView
GroupActivate ExplorerGroup
send, ^v
return
}
```

Comment: Check if `wParam` is different in both cases

Comment: @Oleg To be honest im not really sure what that means. Nor do i understand if I knew what it meant what to do with that information. 

I did  a search and im understanding that when any media is inserted it triggers a "WM_DEVICECHANGE" with a "DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL" event. Im not sure how to translate this information into the script

Comment: I did some further digging and i found the solution:

OnMessage(0x0219, "WM_DEVICECHANGE")
return

WM_DEVICECHANGE(wParam, lParam, msg, hwnd)    ; http://msdn.com/library/aa363480(vs.85,en-us)
{
    static DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL        := 0x8000    ; A device or piece of media has been inserted and is now available.


    if (wParam = DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL)
        DeviceCheck(True)
}

DeviceCheck(change)
{
GroupAdd, ExplorerGroup,,ShellView
GroupActivate ExplorerGroup

send, <#{right}
send, ^a
send, ^c
GroupAdd, ExplorerGroup,,ShellView
GroupActivate ExplorerGroup
send, ^v
}

Comment: Please, post your solution as an answer in code form and accept it, if its working. This way you can help other users who are searching for a solution of similar problems.